# How to stop an actively running for loop

Tags: bash, ubuntu

This might be a silly question. I wanted to copy thousands of files from a remote server to my local machine using `scp`. I ran the below command directly on the command line of the remote server (after logging in with `ssh`)

```
for file in $(ls <SOURCE_DIR>)
do scp $file <LOCAL_ID>@<LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS>:<TARGET_DIR>
done
```

But after running this I realized that `<TARGET_DIR>` is owned by root, so the for loop requests a password, and if I enter the password it throws a `Permission denied` error message. This is repeating over and over again every loop cycle. Is there any way to get out of the for loop without pressing `Ctrl + C` thousands (the number of files in `<SOURCE_DIR>`) of times? Both the server and local use Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Try pushing it to background using `Ctrl-Z`, and kill it with `kill %1`. (process should be `%1`. Make sure using `bg`)

Comment: You can also condition continued looping on successful completion of the `scp` command, e.g. `scp $file <LOCAL_ID>@<LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS>:<TARGET_DIR> || break` At least then if something isn't right with the `scp` command the loop will exit on its own.

Comment: And do not iterate over the ls output, but scp from the source dir, or better use rsync rather than scp. And get ssh key pairs with hosts permissions to avoid needing password for each operation.

Comment: Thanks @User10482, I tried `Ctrl-Z`, but it only sends one loop cycle (not the entire for loop) into background, so I still need to repeat the same things thousands of times to kill the entire for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Bash itself will not let you access remote host , but you can use SSH:

**Step 1:** On your local PC generate key to perform password-free authentication later

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

It will ask you to enter passphrase. If you want your bash script to be fully non-interactive, you can opt not to use any password.

**Step 2:** Copy you public key to the remote host and paste it in .ssh/authorized_keys

**Step 3:** Use `scp` to copy files:

```
$ scp -ir .ssh/sshfile username@host:/sourcedirectory targetdirectory
```

The above command will copy all the files and folders in the respective source directory in the server

Comment: Does this also work when the target directory is owned by root with 755 permission (writable only by the root)?

Comment: Also, how can I stop the currently running for loop? I can't shut down or reboot the machine because it is a server shared with many other users.

Comment: @JunghoonShin , this will work for root also , just copy the public into .ssh directory in root home. For stopping try ctrl z to send the process into background and kill it respectively . If the answer helped , accept the answer to close the question

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately ctrl z sends only one loop cycle (not the entire for loop) into background, so I still need to press ctrl z thousands of times to get out of the for loop..